# Use a Specific date in SQL Oracle Formula

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

```
CASE 
WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF ( SQL_TSI_DAY , "Employee"."ABAY Start Date" , 
        CAST ( Evaluate (  'TO_DATE(%1,%2)' AS CHAR , 
                   CAST ( YEAR ( CURRENT_DATE ) AS VARCHAR ( 4 ) ) 
                   || RIGHT ( '0' || CAST  ( MONTH ( CURRENT_DATE ) AS VARCHAR ( 2 ) ) , 2 ) 
                   || '11' , 'YYYYMMDD' ) AS DATE ) ) > 120 
THEN  '121+ Days' 
WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF ( SQL_TSI_DAY , "Employee"."ABAY Start Date" , 
        CAST ( Evaluate (  'TO_DATE(%1,%2)' AS CHAR , 
                   CAST ( YEAR ( CURRENT_DATE ) AS VARCHAR ( 4 ) ) 
                   || RIGHT ( '0' || CAST  ( MONTH ( CURRENT_DATE ) AS VARCHAR ( 2 ) ) , 2 ) 
                   || '11' , 'YYYYMMDD' ) AS DATE ) ) BETWEEN 91  AND 120 
THEN  '91-120 Days' 
WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF ( SQL_TSI_DAY , "Employee"."ABAY Start Date" , 
        CAST ( Evaluate (  'TO_DATE(%1,%2)' AS CHAR , 
                   CAST ( YEAR ( CURRENT_DATE ) AS VARCHAR ( 4 ) ) 
                   || RIGHT ( '0' || CAST  ( MONTH ( CURRENT_DATE ) AS VARCHAR ( 2 ) ) , 2 ) 
                   || '11' , 'YYYYMMDD' ) AS DATE ) ) BETWEEN 61  AND 90 
THEN  '61-90 Days' 
WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF ( SQL_TSI_DAY , "Employee"."ABAY Start Date" , 
        CAST ( Evaluate (  'TO_DATE(%1,%2)' AS CHAR , 
                   CAST ( YEAR ( CURRENT_DATE ) AS VARCHAR ( 4 ) ) 
                   || RIGHT ( '0' || CAST  ( MONTH ( CURRENT_DATE ) AS VARCHAR ( 2 ) ) , 2 ) 
                   || '11' , 'YYYYMMDD' ) AS DATE ) ) BETWEEN 31  AND 60 
THEN  '31-60 Days' 
WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF ( SQL_TSI_DAY , "Employee"."ABAY Start Date" , 
        CAST ( Evaluate (  'TO_DATE(%1,%2)' AS CHAR , 
                   CAST ( YEAR ( CURRENT_DATE ) AS VARCHAR ( 4 ) ) 
                   || RIGHT ( '0' || CAST  ( MONTH ( CURRENT_DATE ) AS VARCHAR ( 2 ) ) , 2 ) 
                   || '11' , 'YYYYMMDD' ) AS DATE ) ) < 31 
THEN  '0-30 Days' 
ELSE  '0-30 Days' 
END
```

Instead of using the **Current date** I will like to use 11-October-2015.
How can I use that in the code above ?

Comment: Are you certain this should be tagged for Oracle?  You're using quite a few functions that are not native to Oracle's SQL dialect.  Now, perhaps you have built your own `RIGHT` and `MONTH` and `EVALUATE` functions.  But I would suspect that you are really using a different database.

Comment: This question has wrong tags - there is no `timestampdiff` nor `evaluate` function in Oracle.

Comment: Actually the formula above does work. But I will like to put a specific date October-11-2015

Comment: The question from comments is about your database engine, not whether your example compiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use presentation variable for example @{pv_date}. You can create a dashboard with prompt and try to pass a value to the variable.

CASE 
WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF ( SQL_TSI_DAY , "Employee"."ABAY Start Date" , 
  CAST ( Evaluate ( 'TO_DATE(%1,%2)' AS CHAR , 
  CAST ( YEAR ( @{pv_date}) AS VARCHAR ( 4 ) ) 
  || RIGHT ( '0' || CAST ( MONTH ( @{pv_date}) AS VARCHAR ( 2 ) ) , 2 )

Answer (score 0):

How to specify a date literal to represent October 11th 2015:

1. Use an ANSI date literal: `DATE '2015-10-11'`
2. Use a string literal and convert it to a date using the corresponding [format mask](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm): `TO_DATE( '2015-10-11', 'YYYY-MM-DD' )`

The second option can depend on the NLS settings whereas the first (ANSI) option does not. I.e. `TO_DATE( '11-OCT-2015', 'DD-MON-YYYY' )` will not work if the abbreviation for the 10th calendar month is not `OCT` in your language and you may need to specify the correct parameters like this:

```
TO_DATE( '11-OKT-2015', 'DD-MON-YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = dutch' )
```